# Software Updater in 14.04.5 LTS - How Does This Relate to The APT?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, system

The computer Details window (Device name/Memory/Processor/Graphics/OS type/Disk) at bottom right says "System Up-To-Date".

Yet, after "Checking for updates.../Downloading from archive.ubuntu.com" Software Updater reports "Updated software has been issued since Ubuntu 14.04 was released. Do you want to install it now?/>Details of updates/649.8 MB will be downloaded./Install Now".

Why this apparent conflict - and how does the Software Updater functionality relate to the updating possible through the Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)?

Comment: Try to update first, maybe there is a fix for this specific bug among all those updates.

Comment: I've tried update and dist-upgrade but no joy.  Each time I try installing the updates found by Software Updater it freezes at "Configuring grub-efi-amd64", trashing the OS. I've had to restore the OS to factory state using the Dell Recovery tool four times now.

Comment: You may not have the time/humor to try this, but here we go, _(better from a clean system)_ run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Reboot. Then run `sudo apt full-upgrade`, using the new `apt` app, which is a wrapper for `apt-get`.

Comment: I'll give it a go - but I'm beginning to wonder if my time would be better spent ditching the Dell pre-installed 14.04 this laptop came with, wiping the hard drive and trying to install a standard image 14.04 - even if I then have to work out what other drivers, etc I need to get it to work with the Inspiron 15-3552.

Comment: @dgonzalez - On a freshly restored-to-factory OS, I didn’t get as far as the reboot but the lengthy first step produced several “your installation appears to be broken” messages and eventually paused with a window titled "Configuring grub-efi-amd64" which said "A new version of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified. What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub?" (7 options). This tallies with Software Updater crashing at the same step.